# How do you delete a record by value in C#, LiteDB?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, litedb

```
    private void DeleteIncomeTransactionBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var incomeTransactions = DbContext.GetInstance().GetCollection<IncomeTransaction>("income_transactions")
                   .FindAll();

        var code = inputTransactions.SelectedText;
        var ensure = DbContext.GetInstance().GetCollection<IncomeTransaction>("income_transactions").EnsureIndex(r => r.TransactionCode);

        var query = DbContext.GetInstance().GetCollection<IncomeTransaction>("income_transactions").Query()
            .Where(r => r.TransactionCode == code)
            .Select(r => r.Id);

        DbContext.GetInstance().GetCollection<IncomeTransaction>("income_transactions").Delete(query));

    }
```

I want to delete a record by selected index(TransactionCode) of a drop down. In this code I first tried to find a record by selected index and then using this find an ID of this record. Then delete the record with this ID. Please help me with this error.
**My error:
Cannot convert from "LiteDB.ILiteQueryableResult" to "LiteDB.BSON value".**

Comment: Please help!!!!

Comment: collection.`Delete()` method expects single input argument as BsonValue, you cannot pass `var query`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `DeleteMany` method:

```cs
var deletedCount = DbContext.GetInstance()
.GetCollection<IncomeTransaction>("income_transactions")
.DeleteMany(r => r.TransactionCode == code);
```

This will return the number of records deleted.